# Why is navigable correct?

Tags: word-usage, suffixes, word-formation, endings

I corrected someone using "navigatable" when they meant "navigable". They wanted to know why it is the latter. Does anyone know? Is there a reason?

Comment: The English language shuns reason every chance it gets...

Comment: This seems to be common with adjectives derived from verbs ending in -ate. See: impregnable, abominable, irritable, innumerable.

Comment: @79037662  Rotable (not rotatable) conjugable (not conjugatable) demonstrable (not demonstratable)

Comment: @NigelJ - Oh no!!!  You mean there are exceptions to the rules of English???

Comment: @Hot Licks Britannia ruled the waves. Her ruler apparently wasn't that straight.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have an answer for why *navigate* yields *navigable* instead of *navigatable*; but in doing so, *navigable* is by no means a rule breaker among its closest peers. In fact, English has at least eight word pairs involving verbs with a *-gate* ending and adjectives with a -*gable* ending, as confirmed by *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2010):

- **investigate** --> **investigable**
- **irrigate** --> **irrigable**
- **litigate** --> **litigable**
- **mitigate** --> **mitigable**
- **navigate** --> **navigable**
- **obligate** --> **obligable**
- **propagate** --> **propagable**
- **segregate** --> **segregable**

*AHDEL* doesn't list any similar -*gable* adjective form for a larger group of at least seventeen -*gate* verbs:

- **abrogate**
- **aggregate**
- **arrogate**
- **castigate**
- **conjugate**
- **congregate**
- **corrugate**
- **delegate**
- **derogate**
- **elongate**
- **fumigate**
- **instigate**
- **interrogate**
- **relegate**
- **subjugate**
- **subrogate**
- **supererogate**

But on the other hand, it doesn't list ***any*** adjectives of the form -*gatable*. For these reasons, it seems fair to say that, within the subset of -*able* adjectives associated with verbs ending in -*gate*, *navigable* follows the standard pattern—the same one that the other seven -*able* adjectives associated with -*gate* verbs follow.

Comment: By the way, if I had to guess which of the seventeen uncommitted "-gate" verbs would be most likely to have an "-able" adjective of the form "-gatable" rather than "-gable," it would be **elongate** --> **elongatable**, simply because _elongate_ is the only verb in the group in which the letter preceding "-gate" is a consonant rather than a vowel. There is something uniquely disturbing about the option **elongable**.

Comment: I find _castrable_ more disturbing.

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary defines ***[navigatable](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/navigatable)*** as a misspelling of ***[navigable](https://www.etymonline.com/word/navigable#etymonline_v_31052)*** made from the verb “navigate” (possibly nonstandard):

> - 1992, Peter Sammartino and William Roberts, Sicily: An Informal History‎, page 45:
>     *Rivers were made navigatable, irrigation was improved, and the use of hydraulics was greatly increased.*
> - 1998, Flexible Query Answering Systems‎[3](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-able#etymonline_v_49), page 83:
>     *The second is that it has potentials for information exploration, because the displayed network is navigatable.*

Probably because of the common usage of the suffix 
***[-able](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-able#etymonline_v_49)*** often applied to verbs in English:

> common termination and word-forming element of English adjectives (typically based on verbs) and generally adding a notion of "capable of; allowed; worthy of; requiring; to be ______ed,"

Etymonline

Comment: Thus hated, hateable. Debated, debatable. Rated, rateable or ratable. Navigated?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - it is a misusage, possibly non standard they say. Actually navigable entered the English language in mid-15C directly from French “navigable” (see link)

Comment: @user067531, why don't you incorporate that comment into the answer? It is much more directly responsive to the OP's wondering **why** *navigable* is the correct form than what is in the answer now.

Comment: I don't understand how a misspelling can be other than non-standard. Unless there's a broadened definition of misspelling: 'a spelling once considered incorrect, but now acceptable'. Which I'm not aware of.

Comment: It entered from French, as mentioned. French etymology is off-topic, but French *[navigable](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/navigable)* comes from the French *naviguer*. Why there is a "t" in navigate is another question, but I'm inclined to blame Latin.